# Open modal on menuItem click

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to greet the user of my app with a modal once they click on a specific menuItem in the sidebar of my ShinyDashboard. Here's a simple recreation of my previous attempt:

```
# libraries

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## UI ##

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
                menuItem("Subitems", tabName = "subitems",
                         menuSubItem("Upload", "upload"),
                         menuSubItem("Browse", "browse")
                ),
                menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets")
                )
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput('tab')
    )
)

## server ##

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$tab <- renderUI({
    paste("The selected tab is", input$sidebarmenu)
  })

  observeEvent(input$sidebarmenu == "widgets", {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(title = "You selected Widgets", "Or did you?")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The goal is to open the modal only when the menuItem `widgets` is selected. Despite the condition `input$sidebarmenu == "widgets"`, this does not happen. Rather, the modal is displayed any time the user switches menuItems. Why is this the case and how can I do this properly? 
Thank you in advance for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the `observeEvent`

```
  observeEvent(input$sidebarmenu, {
    req(input$sidebarmenu == "widgets")
    showModal(
      modalDialog(title = "You selected Widgets", "Or did you?")
    )
  })
```

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I need. Do you happen to know what was wrong with my initial attempt?

Comment: yes, `observeEvent` isnt a true or false evaluation, its a type of reactive and will fire everytime something changes to the triggers which is the `input$sidebarmenu`

Comment: Very useful to know this. Thank you for your help and time.